# The smallest extension field of $\mathbb{F}_3$ containing all the zeros of $f(x)=x^{11}-1$

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, splitting-field

Firstly notice that $f(1)=0$ so $f(x)=(x+2)g(x)$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$ for some $g$. Moreover, $\text{ord}_{11}3 = 5$, ie $5$ is the smallest exponent $t$ such that $3^t=1 \mod 11$, so $5$ is the lcm of all the degrees of the factors of $f$, hence $f(x)=(x+2)g(x)h(x)$ with $\deg(g)=\deg(h)=5$.

Hence the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$ is $L=\mathbb{F}_{3^5}$. Now, is $L$ the smallest extension of $\mathbb{F}_3$ containing all the zeros of $f(x)$? How to prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for the smallest field extension of $\Bbb F_3$ which contains a primitive $11$-th root of unity.

You're right that the smallest $t$ such that $11$ divides $3^t-1$ (which is the order of the multiplicative group of $\Bbb F_{3^t}$) is $t=5$.
Since the group is cyclic it contains all $11$-th roots of unity. That's it.

Add: We have $3^5-1= 11\cdot 22$ and so if $\omega$ is a primitive element of $\Bbb F_{3^5}$, then $\omega^{22}$ is a primitive $11$-th root of unity.

Comment: Thank you! So the splitting field of a polynomial $f$ is always the smallest field containing all the zeros of $f$?

Comment: That is the definition of a splitting field.

Comment: @KentaS Ok thanks! Could you give a hint about the following? Given $w$ primitive element of $F_{3^5}$, for which $i\in\mathbb N$ the element $w^i$ is a zero of an irreducible factor of $x^{11}-1$?

Comment: Many thanks @Wuestenfux. I have a doubt though, you said that $w^{22}$ is a zero of $x^{11}-1$ right? But is it also a zero of an irreducible factor of $x^{11}-1$?

Comment: @soundwave Being a zero of $x^{11}-1$ is equivalent to being a zero of an irreducible factor of $x^{11}-1$.

Comment: @KentaS thanks didnt know about that